# Validation Class Error

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-intent, android-studio

I am trying to register a user in my android studio project app, but before sending or registering the data, I am using a "validations.java" class which validates the inputs and then, proceeds the registration.

Here is the code for: **register.java**

```
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.MotionEvent;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        /**
         * Created by Tanishq on 15-11-2015.
         */

    public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

        public EditText editname;
        public EditText editemail;
        public EditText editmobile;
        public EditText editpassword;
        public EditText editrepassword;

        String error_code="";
        boolean flagmob = false;
        boolean flagemail = false;
        boolean flagpass = false;
        private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/class/register.php";
        String check="";
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.register);


            editname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
            editemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
            editmobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);
            editpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
            editrepassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.repassword);
        }

        public void onregister(View view)
        {

            validations vd = new validations();
            int k = vd.validate();


            if(k==1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(register.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else
            {
               int len1 = error_code.length();
                for(int i =0; i<-len1; i++)
                {
                    char c = error_code.charAt(i);
                    if(c=='m')
                    {
                        flagmob=true;
                    }
                    else if(c=='e')
                    {
                        flagemail=true;
                    }
                    else if(c=='p')
                    {
                        flagpass=true;
                    }
                }

                if(flagmob=true)
                {
                    editmobile.setHint("10 DIGIT VALID NUMBER");
                    editmobile.setText("");
                    editmobile.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
                }

                if(flagemail=true)
                {
                    editemail.setHint("ENTER VALID EMAIL ID");
                    editemail.setText("");
                    editemail.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
                }

                if(flagpass=true)
                {
                    editpassword.setHint("Passwords Don't Match");
                    editpassword.setText("");
                    editpassword.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
                    editrepassword.setHint("Passwords Don't Match");
                    editrepassword.setText("");
                    editrepassword.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
                }

                check = "";
                error_code="";
            }
        }
    }
```

The **validation class** code is as follows: I have used inheritance to get the parameters from the register class.

```
import com.classifiedwale.android.register;
public class validations extends register {
public int validate() {
int validation = 1;
int evalid = 1;
int mvalid = 1;
int pvalid = 1;

        check = editmobile.getText().toString();
        if (check.length() > 10) {
            mvalid = 0;
            error_code = error_code + "m";
        }

        //Email Validation
        check = editemail.getText().toString();
        char c;
        int length = check.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            c = check.charAt(i);
            if (c == '@') {

            } else {
                error_code = error_code + "e";
                evalid = 0;
            }
        }

        check = editpassword.getText().toString();
        String check2 = editrepassword.getText().toString();
        if (check.equals(check2)) {
            validation = 1;
        } else {
            error_code = error_code + "p";
            pvalid = 0;
        }


        if (evalid != 0 && mvalid != 0 && pvalid != 0) {
            validation = 1;
        } else {
            validation = 0;
        }

        return validation;
}
}
```

The error however comes out to be this:

```
11-15 07:12:42.210  19637-19637/com.classifiedwale.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:278)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.classifiedwale.android.validations.validate(validations.java:17)
            at com.classifiedwale.android.register.onregister(register.java:49)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please let me know the error, I think its somewhat related to wrong inheritance of extending the class.

Comment: Which line in the class `validations` is line number 17 (which throws the NPE)? Have you debugged your program?

Comment: Hi, I am relatively new to the android studio, and android development - So I haven't debugged it, since I don't know how to. Here is the screenshot of code with line numbers:

The error now occurs on line number 13(After Formatting) and this is the code on line 13: http://prntscr.com/92xmyg

Comment: well first of all class names should start with a capital letter. Java is case-sensitive

Comment: @helldawg13 Oh, I'll change that asap!

Comment: `editmobile` is null, because `validations extends register`, which `extends AppCompatActivity`, and you can't instantiate an `Activity` with `new`. `onCreate()` will never run, so your `View`s never get initialized. Don't subclass `register` for your `validations` class. Make it a regular class, and pass any data it needs through constructors or setters.

Comment: Thank-you so much, but how will that be implemented? It would be great if  I could see it in a code :)

Comment: As @MikeM. says you want to build a validation class so that you dont have all the validation code inside register. What you can do is build methods in validation class with parameters received from the register class.

Comment: Oh! Got it, will try that! thank-you so much Mike M, helldawg13 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like this:

**Validation class:**

```
public class Validation {

    public boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email){
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    public void validateMobile(String mobile){
        if (mobile != null){
            if (mobile.length() > 10){
                //do stuff with name
            }
        }
    }

    public void validatePassword(String password, String retypePassword){
        if (password != null && retypePassword != null){
            if (password.equals(retypePassword)){
                //do stuff with password
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Register class:**

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText editname;
    public EditText editemail;
    public EditText editmobile;
    public EditText editpassword;
    public EditText editrepassword;

    String error_code="";
    boolean flagmob = false;
    boolean flagemail = false;
    boolean flagpass = false;
    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/class/register.php";
    String check="";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);


        editname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        editemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        editmobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        editpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        editrepassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.repassword);
    }

    public void onregister(View view) {

        Validation validation = new Validation();
        String name = editname.getText().toString();
        String email = editemail.getText().toString();
        String mobile = editmobile.getText().toString();
        String password = editpassword.getText().toString();
        String retypePassword = editrepassword.getText().toString();

        String validatedMobile = validation.validateMobile(mobile);
        boolean validatedEmail = validation.isEmailValid(email);
        String validatedPassword = validation.validatePassword(password, retypePassword);
        //do stuff with validated data

    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Amazing, gotcha, will try in a bit. Thankyou :)

Comment: no problemm i run into simmilar problemm while ago so anytime